# Standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused “exec format error”

Tags: go, dockerfile, webassembly

The following code generates an error:
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused “exec format error”

Any pointers to what I’m doing wrong?

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
 
ENV GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js

WORKDIR /build

COPY . .

COPY wasm_exec.js . 
COPY server.go . 
COPY main.wasm . 
COPY manifest.json . 
COPY sw.js . 
COPY wasm_exec.js . 
COPY app.js . 
COPY index.html .

EXPOSE 8989 
ENTRYPOINT ["./server.go"]
```

Comment: You need to compile `./server.go` (go build etc.) and then have that resulting binary as your entry-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To use `dos2unix` fix your files' format, which maybe changed by git from lf to crlf
2. go build before copy to docker, then, copy and execute the bin
3. if you don't want to do pre-built, the last line should be `ENTRYPOINT ["go","run","./server.go"]`

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to execute `server.go` file without compiling you need to compile `server.go` to get the executable which then can be used as executable.

```
go build server.go
```

Or you can directly run it using

```
go run server.go
```

Comment: After adding to the end of the Dockerfile
CMD ["go", "run", "server.go"] 
I get a new error: 
fork/exec /tmp/go-build004673479/b001/exe/server: exec format error